# "Remove unused using statements"... but keep a few default ones

Tags: c#, visual-studio, using

Does anyone know of an automated way to remove unused `using` statements from C# files, but keep certain ones that the developer specifies?

Comment: How annoying when a useful question like this is "closed".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CodeMaid has a feature for this purpose. It's a free Visual Studio extension. Once it's installed, you can specify the using statements that you will always want to keep.

[image]